# Loop through DIV elements and get dynamically added text inputs - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a form on a web page that allows for dynamically added divs with text inputs inside them (via JavaScript) into a div called "actorsDivHTML". So the structure is as follows:

```
<div name="actorsDivHTML">

    <div name="actor[]">
        <input type="text" name="actorName[]">
        <div name="actorInfoDiv[]">
            <input type="text" name="actorInfo[]">
            <input type="text" name="actorInfo[]">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div name="actor[]">
        <input type="text" name="actorName[]">
        <div name="actorInfoDiv[]">
            <input type="text" name="actorInfo[]">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Note: I am unsure if a div is allowed to be used the same way an input is -> ie. "div[]"

My aim is to allow the user to dynamically add as many "actors" as possible with as many "actorInfo" inputs for each "actor" as they require. When the user submits the form, I have a PHP file that will need to get each "actor" and each "actorInfo" from the "actorsDivHTML" div.

My questions are; 
what is the best way to name each div so the info can be easily extracted by the PHP script? What is the best way to iterate through the div and extract the information that I need (ie. each actor and the info about them), and place them into an array of the following structure:

```
Array(
    [actor] => Array([0] => "name", [1] => Array([0] => "info1", [1] => "info2", etc.))
    [actor] => Array([0] => "second name", [1] => Array([0] => "actor 2 info1", etc.))
)
```

Happy to clarify and share more code!

Cheers!

[EDIT: 1]

In response to Pupil:

I have updated my Div's to look like this:

```
<div class="actorTest">

   <div name="actorDivPlace">
       <input type="text" name="actorNameTest[name]">
       <div name="actorInfoDiv">
           <input type="text" name="actorNameTest[name][]">
           <input type="text" name="actorNameTest[name][]">
        </div>
   </div>

    <div name="actorDivPlace">
        <input type="text" name="actorNameTest[name]">
        <div name="actorInfoDiv">
            <input type="text" name="actorNameTest[name][]">
            <input type="text" name="actorNameTest[name][]">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and when I run `print_r($_POST["actorNameTest"])` I only get the last actor:

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => second info [1] => second second info) )
```

Comment: `div` elements do NOT have a `name` attribute but you can legitimately use `data-name="actordivplace"` etc - though this is only useful for accessing via javascript anyway and is never transmitted via form submission

Answer (score 1):

1) PHP cannot access anything from your `<div>`. Only html can do that and PHP will only pick values from your `<input>` which is looking very bad.

2) actorInfoDiv[] and actor[] are both invalid HTML names (They can neither be resolved correctly by CSS or JavaScript).

3) You shouldn't be using `name` to identify `<div>`'s. You should be using one of `id` or `class`.

4) Try using the following structure:

```
<div name="actorsDivHTML"> <!-- I kept name here so I wouldn't mess up with your javascript code. You should really consider using an id for this. -->
<!-- OR -->
<!-- <div id="actorsDivHTML"> -->

    <div class="actor">
        <input type="text" name="actor[name][]">
        <div class="actorInfoDiv">
            <input type="text" name="actor[info1][]">
            <input type="text" name="actor[info1][]">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actor">
        <input type="text" name="actor[name][]">
        <div class="actorInfoDiv">
            <input type="text" name="actor[info2][]">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

That makes a more logical and accurate HTML code.

## Php to parse the data

```
<?php

// We need to ensure that the data exist.
if(isset($_POST['actor'])){

    $parsed_data = [];

    // We will be using this number to get the info for 
    // the current name in the list when we iterate 
    // through the names.
    $i = 1;

    // Check the sent data by their names...
    foreach($_POST['actor']['name'] as $key => $value){

        // Add the name to an array
        // Looking at: [0] => "name"
        $array = [$value];

        // Create an array to hold the info's
        $array_infos = [];

        // Get all info posts that associates with the 
        // name in the current position
        // Looking at: [1] => Array([0] => "info1", [1] => "info2", etc.)
        foreach($_POST['actor']["info{$i}"] as $value_info){

            // Append the infos into the value_info array
            // NB: This makes sure that our data is exactly 
            // in the order the user enters it.
            array_push($array_infos, $value_info);
        }

        // Add the infos unto the end of the main array.
        array_push($array, $array_infos);

        // Add the main array to the array of parsed data results.
        // Looking at: [actor] => Array([0] => "name", [1] => Array([0] => "info1", [1] => "info2", etc.))
        array_push($parsed_data, ['actor' => $array]);
        $i++;
    }

    // Do anything you want with the result.
    // I choose to print it out here.
    print_r($parsed_data);
}

?>
```

## Here is a ready to run example:

```
<?php

// We need to ensure that the data exist.
if(isset($_POST['actor'])){

    $parsed_data = [];

    // We will be using this number to get the info for 
    // the current name in the list when we iterate 
    // through the names.
    $i = 1;

    // Check the sent data by their names...
    foreach($_POST['actor']['name'] as $key => $value){

        // Add the name to an array
        // Looking at: [0] => "name"
        $array = [$value];

        // Create an array to hold the info's
        $array_infos = [];

        // Get all info posts that associates with the 
        // name in the current position
        // Looking at: [1] => Array([0] => "info1", [1] => "info2", etc.)
        foreach($_POST['actor']["info{$i}"] as $value_info){

            // Append the infos into the value_info array
            // NB: This makes sure that our data is exactly 
            // in the order the user enters it.
            array_push($array_infos, $value_info);
        }

        // Add the infos unto the end of the main array.
        array_push($array, $array_infos);

        // Add the main array to the array of parsed data results.
        // Looking at: [actor] => Array([0] => "name", [1] => Array([0] => "info1", [1] => "info2", etc.))
        array_push($parsed_data, ['actor' => $array]);
        $i++;
    }

    // Do anything you want with the result.
    // I choose to print it out here.
    print_r($parsed_data);
}

?>
<form method="post">

    <div name="actorsDivHTML"> <!-- I kept name here so I wouldn't mess up with your javascript code. You should really consider using an id for this. -->
    <!-- OR -->
    <!-- <div id="actorsDivHTML"> -->

        <div class="actor">
            <input type="text" name="actor[name][]">
            <div class="actorInfoDiv">
                <input type="text" name="actor[info1][]">
                <input type="text" name="actor[info1][]">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="actor">
            <input type="text" name="actor[name][]">
            <div class="actorInfoDiv">
                <input type="text" name="actor[info2][]">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should mark it as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following are guidelines:

1) Only HTML `<form>` elements are posted. No `<div>s` will be posted.

2) You need to use multiple values form elements for getting vector data.

```
   <div name="actor">
        <input type="text" name="actorName[name]">
        <div name="actorInfoDiv[]">
            <input type="text" name="actorName[name][]">
            <input type="text" name="actorName[name][]">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Post the form, and print the `$_POST`, you will get required array.